# How to pass props down to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

So in my main component, I send props to a child component like this:

```
<div className={styles.navBar}>
          <MasterNavBar color={false} scrollChange={true} />
</div>
```

MasterNavBar gets access to the props correctly, but I need MasterNavBar to pass those props to a child component called NavBar, which I currently do like this:

```
<NavBar props />
```

However, when I do this, the props are not accessible in my NavBar component file. For example, in NavBar, doing props.color to get my color prop returns undefined. So, am I passing my props incorrectly, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on which props NavBar is expecting. If you don't care about typing (either with typescript or react PropTypes) you can simply do like this:

```
<NavBar {...props} />
```

However this is not the best approach and can lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

As ***Antonio Pantano*** said, you can pass the whole props to the `<NavBar {...props}/>` component, but this is a bad practice way. This [article](https://www.codementor.io/blog/react-optimization-5wiwjnf9hj#11-spreading-props-on-dom-elements) explained why it is a bad practice way. So you can pass the `MasterNavBar` props to its child in these two ways:

```
const MasterNavBar = (props) => {
 /* 
      rest of your code                    
*/ 

  return <NavBar color={props.color} scrollChange={props.scrollChange}/>

}
```

or

```
const MasterNavBar = ({color, scrollChange}) => {
 /* 
      rest of your code                    
*/ 
  return <NavBar color={color} scrollChange={scrollChange}/>

}
```

You can change the name of `NavBar` props as you wish, and you access them in the `NavBar` component by these names.